# Nuget Package Manager Fails To Install Some Packages For UWP Apps

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I haven't had problems with nuget until now, i created a blank a UWP project and decided to add some few nuget packages to it and it keeps saying 'Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for App1'. But when i do this a WPF project it successfully install. Does anyone here knows why this is happening or is also ?

Comment: can you provide some Nuget console output?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with other packages. The problem is that many NuGet packages don't seem to be compatible with UWP. This incompatibility info is shown in the output console rather than the error console of Visual Studio.
See also [.NETcore, UWP - can't install NuGet package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096376/netcore-uwp-cant-install-nuget-package).